# Randomly vary the slope of triangular wave in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graphics, simulink, matlab-figure, figure

The code below produces a triangular wave:

```
x=0:0.1:3;
f=(mod(x,1)<=0.3).*(1-1/0.3.*mod(x,1))+(0.3<mod(x,1)).*(1/0.7.*(mod(x,1)-0.3));
plot(x,f)
```

[image: wave]

I need to vary the slope (0.3 value randomly) for each cycle (1 seconds).

For example

- 0-1 = 0.4 (random number)
- 1-2 = 0.7 (random number)
- .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rand(N,1) to get an N element column vector where each element is a random number between 0 and 1. Set N to be how ever many values are indicated by your "......." at the end of the post. As each cycle "(1 second)" increases an integer counter and use that counter to move though the random array. For example if the counter is called "count" use rand(N,1)(count) instead of "0.3".

Comment: How can i do this "As each cycle "(1 second)" increases an integer counter and use that counter to move though the random array"?

Comment: It's not clear from your post where the "seconds" are, so I'm not sure how to answer. Are the x supposed to be seconds or are the seconds some other part of the problem that you are looping over but not showing in the code snippet?

Comment: if the x are seconds, I guess you could just include some if statements in the f function definition to do the cycling. Like, "if(x<1)
a=rand(3,1)(1) 
end", where a is the thing to replace "0.3". And so on.

Comment: Yes X is in seconds. for every 1 seconds the x=0.3 value should be vary randomly. What correction to be made in code ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't do your homework for you. You need to modify the f function, and you can use the matlab functions rand and you will need to add some logic to the f function (like a few if/else statements). Or, if you don't want to do it that way, you could write three different functions similar to f but with a different random value in place of "0.3", e.g., f1, f2, f3. These f1, f2, f3 are really arrays whose elements are the functions evaluated at x. You could then concatenate the f1, f2, f3 arrays and plot the resulting array using the plot function.